# How to extract Middle Names using formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to:

1. extract clients' middle name(s) from a field; or
2. delete the first and last name, leaving the middle name(s)

but I am stuck. I can remove the last word using

```
=LEFT(TRIM(A1),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~",LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",""))))-1)
```

I can remove the first word by

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))
```

But I can't combine them. I have looked online and found this:

```
=TRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE((TRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),0*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1),"")))," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),(1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-1)*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1),""))
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Care to share sample data?

Comment: Without examples, I would test for the existence of two spaces ie middle name and proceed. If there is only one space, then assume no middle name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the ' remove the last word ' formula and use it in the ' remove the first word ' formula .

Implementation : Just replace all A1 in the ' remove the first word ' formula with ' remove the last word ' formula .

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(TRIM(A1),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~",LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",""))))-1),LEN(LEFT(TRIM(A1),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~",LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",""))))-1))-FIND(" ",LEFT(TRIM(A1),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","~",LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",""))))-1)))
```

Done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That does help thanks, looks like it works. Only issue I can see is if the person only has two names then it errors out, how would I put and if rule in that returns nothing if the name has two words and then the above formula if more then 2 words.

Comment: just make the output to "" (null) if there is an error, using `=iferror( <full formula> ,"") `